# Creating indexes on big tables - postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to create some regular indexes on a big table (26G), but it takes a lot of time - more than 2 hours. Every index is taking about 11 minutes.

Maybe I'm wrong and I should concentrate on improving the time it takes me to load the data into postgres from oracle (`oracle_fdw`). I preform a lot of inserts into `local_postgresql_table select * from remote_oracle_table` (about 200G), which also takes a lot of time.

If there is a way to change one of the parameters to improve the performance, I would be happy to hear how. Running this query on 26G takes two hours.

Is there a way to improve this operation? Is there a way to improve this operation by improving the hardware (I didn't see that the server is overloaded)?

The parameters that I configured:

```
min_parallel_relation_size = 200MB
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 5 
max_worker_processes = 8 
effective_cache_size = 2500MB
work_mem = 16MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1500MB
shared_buffers = 1500MB
RAM : 5G
```

Comment: `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` - not faster, but low-lock and low-disruption

Comment: So in other words it creates the index in the background ? Lets assume that I used this option, If I select from my table it wont use the index until it done the creation ? I`m searching for a solution that can make the creation faster because I need those indexes in my selects

Comment: Pre-sorting the data externally before database import will make index creation faster. An extra speedup can be had if you can afford to use a database with C locale and collation.

Comment: I bring the data from oracle database via oracle_fdw. When you mean pre-sorting, than I`ll preform sort on the oracle side but order by what ? And what do you mean by C locale and collation?

Comment: Please refer this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99091/create-index-on-a-postgres-table-as-fast-as-possible

Comment: Many of my text columns include hebrew text, If I change the collation (currently UTF8) to C, it might be a problem no ? Where can I check if this collation support hebrew?

Comment: Moreover, I checked the pre-sorting attitude, but I dont think that it will help because I create alot of different indexes on different columns, this means that I need to sort the data before creation of every index isnt it ? It isnt so usefull If I create alot of indexes and not just one.

Comment: What is your `maintenance_work_mem`? If it is default (16MB) then you can safely increase it to something much bigger like 1-2GB, since those operations usually don't run in parallel or not much at least.

Comment: I set it to 1G and it takes 12MIN(Originaly it took 14 minutes  ) to create an index on 26G table. Still I dont think that it is fast enough. What do you think ?  I also increased the max_parallel_workers_per_gather to 5. So parallel only works on select/update/delete/insert ?

Comment: I added all my memory parameters to the main post. Please can you check it out and comment what do you think I can change to improve my preformance ?

Answer (score -1):

[**Visit this blog for the Example of Parallel Query Processing:**](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/11/postgresql-9-6-powerful-parallel-query-processing-full-performance-test-max_worker_processes-max_parallel_workers_per_gather/)

For Parallel Sequential Scanning, in background multiple workers or CPU threads are responsible for executing one single query. We can easily set Parallel Sequential parameter’s value can execute your query 10 times faster.

Using max_worker_processes parameter, in PostgreSQL 9.6, You can change the Process Workers parameter value which is default 8.

Comment: I cant run explain analyze on create index so i cant check if its run in parallel or not ...

Comment: You can check the performance by increasing the parameter max_parallel_workers_per_gather. like Set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4

Comment: I set it to 8, so now I`m waiting to see how much time it is taking to create the index.

Comment: It didnt change anything. When I se the max_parallel_workers_per_gather=8 it took 14 min and when I set it to 4 it also took 14 min.

Comment: Try modifying the parameter maintenance_work_mem if it is still default.

Comment: What value should I set it to ?

Comment: I set it to 128M and it improved to 13minutes. Is there anything else I can do to improve it

Answer (score -1):

One issue with creating X multiple indexes is that if the table size exceeds your cache size then you cannot avoid performing X physical reads of your table.

Many years ago, I got round this on Oracle by starting the builds of multiple indexes in different sessions at the same time. This meant that there was only one physical read of each block for each batch of indexes being created.

The downside is that you need more sort memory to be able to effectively do this.

Might be worth a try.

Comment: I`m running in a loop over a table that includes the sql to create the indexes. How can I create them in different sessions exactly if it is part of a big transaction ?

Comment: I don't think that that would be possible. You also couldn't run multiple `concurrently` index builds at the same time. I would suggest running a test of whether performance can be improved in this way, though, by trying something like three index creations at the same time through different psql connections -- if it takes 33 minutes then disk reads on the table were probably not the performance chokepoint, and if it takes 11 minutes then it was 100% the chokepoint. It probably lies somewhere between, and you'd find that something like 5 simultaneous builds taking 20 minutes is the sweet spot.

Comment: I created simultaneously 3 indexes. The first one took 16 minuts and it was an index on three columns. The second one took 9.5 minutes on one column. The third one took  9.5 minutes and it was an index on two columns.

Comment: I`m thinking mybe to use the alter table xx set unlogged option. Regarding the creation time of the indexes what do you think ?

Comment: One more thing, I saw that during the creation of the indexes there are alot reads from disk.

Comment: On your test, does that mean you achieved three index builds in 16 minutes wall clock time? How long would they have taken if created sequentially? You would certainly see quite a lot of disk activity -- that in itself may not be a problem for you, as that bandwidth is "use it or lose it", unless it causes problems for other sessions. Maybe try six at once.

Comment: Not logging the creation might improve performance. I would try to get as much performance as possible with logging, then try it without to see what improvement it gives.

Comment: The not logging options didnt improve my performance.. I gathered some info and created a new post - can you please read it and advice ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669697/postgresql-9-6-bad-performance-on-big-tables?noredirect=1#comment78301022_45669697

Comment: No. I don't see why you created the new question at all. It's the same problem.

Comment: In this post I mentioned that the index process is the problematic one but I saw that the creation of the tables is also taking alot of time . So I gathered all the info that I had and creatted a new post on both issues. Why it is disturbing you ?

Comment: They are two distinctly different issues. Your new question asks about both. Don't take it personally.