# Slow cross-loading from oracle (oracle-fdw) into PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, performance, oracle-fdw

I created multiple posts in the forum about the performance problem that I have but now after i made some tests and gathered all the info that is needed I'm creating this post.

I have performance issues with two big tables. Those tables are located on an oracle remote database. I'm running the quert : 
`insert into local_postgresql_table select * from oracle_remote_table.`

The first table has 45M records and its size is 23G. The import of the data from the oracle remote database is taking 1 hour and 38 minutes. After that I create 13 regular indexes on the table and it takes 10 minutes per table ->2 hours and 10 minutes in total.

The second table has 29M records and its size is 26G. The import of the data from the oracle remote database is taking 2 hours and 30 minutes. The creation of the indexes takes 1 hours and 30 minutes (some are indexes on one column and the creation takes 5 min and some are indexes on multiples column and it takes 11 min.

Those operation are very problematic for me and I'm searching for a solution to improve the performance. The parameters I assigned :

```
min_parallel_relation_size = 200MB
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 5 
max_worker_processes = 8 
effective_cache_size = 2500MB
work_mem = 16MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1500MB
shared_buffers = 2000MB
RAM : 5G
CPU CORES : 8
```

**-I tried running select count(*) from table in oracle and in postgresql the running time is almost equal.**

**-Before importing the data I drop the indexes and the constraints.**

**-I tried to copy a 23G file from the oracle server to the postgresql server and it took me 12 minutes.**

Please advice how can I continue ? How can I improve something in this operation ?

Comment: link between postgres <-> oracle can be slow, try to extract data from oracle into file and then use `copy` command in postgres to import the data
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: What hardware are you running on?  How much RAM?  And most importantly, what type of disk(s) is your PostgreSQL data stored on?

Comment: Your first table has a rowsize of ~500 bytes; the second table ~1000. Plus 13 indexes : this looks more like a spreadsheet to me.

Comment: How long does it take to move 25 GB across your network?

Comment: Andrew - I have 5G RAM and my disks are virtual disks... joop - What do you mean ? I didnt understand you. Mike and are, I didnt check it yet but is it the main cause for this kind of performance ? I tried putting the tables in nollogging mode but it didnt help either.

Comment: Mike - I tried to copy a 23G file from the oracle server to the postgresql server and it took me 12 minutes.

Comment: This is a repeat posting of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606747/creating-indexes-on-big-tables-postgresql-9-6/45617236?noredirect=1#comment78306928_45617236

Comment: @Mariel *my disks are virtual disks* No, they're real. Somewhere, there are actual storage devices.  What are they? Because that actually *matters*.

Comment: I sent mail to the storage team in the company and I'm waiting for response. Can you guide me to check anything else ?

Comment: Loading data into a database is, for the most part, an IO intensive task. This is like building a beautiful rail dragster with a 1 cylinder lawn mower engine then wondering why the guy next to you in a pinto with a 454 is winning.

The rest of the car does not matter if you are running on a lawn mower engine.

Comment: See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions